# Redshift Serializable isolation violation in glue postactions

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have multiple glue jobs that start at the same time and execute the following postaction - All the glue jobs reference different 'glue_job_unique_table'.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE glue_job_unique_table_inc AS SELECT * FROM glue_job_unique_table
WHERE loadeddtm > ( 
          SELECT coalesce(max(last_loaded_datetime),'1990-01-01') FROM fault_table WHERE ctl_tbl='glue_job_unique_name'
     );

UNLOAD ('select *,extract(year from loadeddtm) as year,extract(month from loadeddtm) as month,extract(day from loadeddtm) as day,extract(hour from loadeddtm) as hour from glue_job_unique_table_inc ')
       // skipped the rest unload syntax

INSERT INTO fault_table
VALUES ('text','glue_job_unique_table',sysdate);

DROP TABLE glue_job_unique_table_inc;

END
```

Multiple glue jobs have been failing with the Serializable isolation violation. I checked in redshift table and found that it is because of 'fault_table'. I can see that multiple jobs are inserting into the same table at same time but not sure how this is affecting the serializability of these transactions. From what i can understand, there is a filter unique to each job when we are selecting the data as well as when inserting into the table, so how two transactions are not able to run concurrently. Can someone tell on why exactly is this error coming and how can we resolve it?

Checked the redshift logs to find what table and transactions are responsible for this. Found the table name but couldnt figure out why the serializability of the two transactions is getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you the table id AND the xids of the conflicting events.  From these xids you can get the actions that are happening that are causing the issue.

In general this error is caused when one transaction is modifying A based on B while another is modifying B based on A.  So it isn't just the updating of the table that is in question but also some process using this result to modify something else.  You need to find the something else (looks like it will be tables glue_job_unique_table and fault_table) and what this other transaction is doing (some other transaction updating glue_job_unique_table based on fault_table).  Follow the breadcrumbs of the xids and you should find the cause.

It could be that you can adjust the timing of this other process but that won't be know until you see what it is.